# Command 8 Interface vs M Audio Project Mixer

Tags: audio-interfaces, controller, m-audio, pro-tools

I am researching into interfaces and control surfaces for Pro Tools (I may be looking to purchase one in the near future).

I'd like the ability to control mixing in pro tools using faders instead of a mouse which is a bit tedious.  I know the Command 8 does this, but the M Audio Project Mixer allows for mic inputs which is very useful.  Which would you say is the best?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the command 8 and it is fine.  I use the 002 as well.  I would suggest getting the Command 8 just now and then the new mbox pro with 4 mic inputs a bit further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on either but I thought I let you know about something that I have been playing around with as a solution that is really cheap and works for ProTools (and other DAW).

AC-7 on the iPad

http://saitarasoftware.com/Site/Home.html

I was looking for a control surface the other day and came across this. It works surprisingly well. I am using it for automation at the moment in Cubase, but I'll be working in other environments soon.

Not an answer to you question sorry, but maybe another option if you have an iPad that could get you out of trouble if you are in a hurry.

Comment: I don't have an iPad unfortunately, but my girlfriend does, I may have to borrow it if she'll let me...

Comment: That's really neat, I'll definitely try that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi there,

I don't think you are comparing like with like the Command 8 is just a control surface and a MIDI interface, it isn't an audio interface. If you want a Command 8 with an audio interface then what you need is a 003 or a secondhand 002 interface from Digidesign.

Mike.

Comment: Just had a look at the 003/002 interfaces.  They do look a lot more like what I had in mind.  Bit too pricey for me though, I shall stick to an MBox 2 for audio input and the like, I don't really need 8 inputs I suppose, just being greedy!  The Command 8 does the job I need.